# Need rigging help for a robotic jaw holder

Tags: mesh, rigging

[image]

So this is what I'm trying to rig, but I'm not too experienced with rigging so I had some problems trying to rig this.

[image: gif]

This is what I currently have and it's obviously bad. I want to make it so it would look the way it would act naturally. Basically:

-The wrinkly black tube needs to stretch normally.

-The red "caps" on the small black tubes need to follow the mesh of the tube it stands on.

-The small black tube on which the red "caps" aren't standing on needs to stay connected to the other small black tube. (I'm not good at naming these.)

-The small black tube holders need to move their black and gray front parts so they wouldn't clip with the screen, my problem is not that, but making the small black tubes stay connected with them.

I don't know how to describe this better but I simply want this mesh to react normally to the rig

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various [constraints](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/introduction.html) can provide the functionality you are looking for.

For the rigid tubing connected to the main column I would add bones in place to move them. To get them to follow the upper arm movement I would add a [Copy Rotation constraint](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/transform/copy_rotation.html), only enable the axes you want to use and adjust the influence so that they rotate less than the main arm. For the lower piece I would use a [StretchTo constraint](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/tracking/stretch_to.html) to keep the end attached to the other tube.

For the flexible tubing going up to the arm, create several small bones to deform the tubing and add a curve to match the rest position of the tubing, then use hooks (see below) to deform the curve and use the curve in a [SplineIK constraint](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/tracking/spline_ik.html) to move the bones you positioned for this.

[image: example armature]

[image]

Setting up hooks can be confusing and a little awkward, the step are -

- Select the upper arm in pose mode.
- Shift select the curve (the outliner can make this easier)
- Enter edit mode for the curve.
- Select the point in the curve that you want to move with the arm.
- Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>*->Hook to Selected Object Bone*

Now exit edit mode and move the armature, the end of the curve should follow the bone. Note that the viewport lags behind with the splineIK but it will be in the right place when rendering. Repeat for the other end of the curve.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything worked normally except for the tubing. When I tried to parent the tube mesh to the bones this happened: https://i.gyazo.com/6454407552aa790fcc9a6bc831d327d6.gif , due to the Spline IK messing up the mesh. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Well actually never mind about that, I fixed it by applying the transform to the rest pose, The way it reacts now however is it just stretches really weirdly and gets bigger, so I just deleted that and parented it normally, works pretty well for what I need.